# Padding on child element doesn't move parent size

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to understand why in the following code, the children `<li>` doesn't move the parent `<ul>` with the padding set to 15px.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box__list {
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0;
}

.box__item {
  color: black;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ul class="box__list">
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box__list">
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKYbYx

The only padding that is working is the `left` and `right`, the `top` and `bottom` are collapsing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you have the `list items` set to `display:inline;` they need to be `display:inline-block;` if you want the top/bottom padding to have an affect.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box__list {
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0;
}

.box__item {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ul class="box__list">
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box__list">
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
    <li class="box__item">A</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `display: inline` of the `.box__item` class. If you change `display` to `inline-block` your problem will be solved.

Inline doesn't push elements vertically:

> An inline element will accept margin and padding, but the element still sits inline as you might expect. Margin and padding will only push other elements horizontally away, not vertically.

Inline-block does:

> An element set to inline-block is very similar to inline in that it will set inline with the natural flow of text (on the "baseline"). The difference is that you are able to set a width and height which will be respected.

You can read about how to use properly the `display` attribute [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).